# how to extract all keys in json array into column when select in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm using PostgreSQL version 12.9

I have a `Table` named `EmployeeFamily` and `family` column is type of `jsonb`

`EmployeeFamily` table is as follows:

| id | first_name | last_name | family |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | B1 | [{"name":"C1","role":"Father"},{"name":"D1","role":"Mother"},{"name":"E1","role":"Brother"}] |
| 2 | A2 | B2 | [{"name":"C2","role":"Father"},{"name":"D2","role":"Mother"},{"name":"F2","role":"Sister"}] |

Now I want a query with below result:

| id | first_name | last_name | family_name | role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | B1 | C1 | Father |
| 2 | A1 | B1 | D1 | Mother |
| 3 | A1 | B1 | E1 | Brother |
| 4 | A2 | B2 | C2 | Father |
| 5 | A2 | B2 | D2 | Mother |
| 6 | A2 | B2 | F2 | Sister |

help me to write query with this result!

Thank's All

Comment: Your JSON value looks very strange. Why the escaped `"`?  Something is wrong there

Comment: I think you're looking for sequential `id` values rather than repeating ones in the result set, aren't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first step, you should know that naming in this database is in lower case.
jsonb stores data in a decomposed binary form; that is, not as an ASCII/UTF-8 string, but as binary code.
in conclusion :

```
SELECT
    e.ID,
    e.first_name,
    e.last_name,
    j.MEMBER -> 'role' AS ROLE,
    j.MEMBER -> 'name' AS NAME 
FROM
    employeefamily e
    CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements (e.FAMILY) j(MEMBER)
```

Comment: What differs between this and the one from LukStorms?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jsonb_array_elements` to unfold the jsonb array.
Then get the fields from the family members.

> ```
> select emp.id, emp.first_name, emp.last_name
> , fam.member->>'name' as family_name
> , fam.member->>'role' as role
> from EmployeeFamily emp
> cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(emp.family) fam(member)
> ```

> | id | first_name | last_name | family_name | role |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | A1 | B1 | C1 | Father |
> | 1 | A1 | B1 | D1 | Mother |
> | 1 | A1 | B1 | E1 | Brother |
> | 2 | A2 | B2 | C2 | Father |
> | 2 | A2 | B2 | D2 | Mother |
> | 2 | A2 | B2 | F2 | Sister |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8c39479a577f0d3639554a40ba3c514d)*

Answer (score 2):

One option would be `jsonb_to_recordset()` function in order the unnest the array of objects such as

```sql
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id, name ) AS id,
       first_name, last_name, name AS family_name, role
  FROM EmployeeFamily,
       jsonb_to_recordset(family) AS (name TEXT, role TEXT)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6edde3f91c1ff4a17195d3b253664ccc)</kbd>